# Translate service does not apply to all components in my angular 14 application

Tags: html, angular, pipe, ngx-translate, angular14

I'm using ngx-translate to make my angular app multilingual. I have a shared module where I import all module that I will use in different places and there where I imported the translation module.

```
 ....
import { FlexLayoutModule } from "@angular/flex-layout";
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { NgxTranslateModule } from "./translate/translate.module";
import { TranslateModule } from "@ngx-translate/core";
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from "@ngx-translate/http-loader";
....
@NgModule({
  exports: [
    ....
    NgxTranslateModule,
    TranslateModule,
    HttpClientModule
........
```

Then I use the service in my layout component, where I have a button in the toolbar to pick the language:

```
 import { TranslateService } from "@ngx-translate/core";

.....
export class FullComponent implements OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
  languageList = [
    { code: "en", label: "English" },
    { code: "fr", label: "Français" },
    { code: "ar", label: "العربية" },
  ];
  public siteLanguage = "English";
....

 constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document,
    private translate: TranslateService,
 ....
  ) {
  
  }

 changeSiteLanguage(localeCode: string): void {
    const selectedLanguage = this.languageList
      .find((language) => language.code === localeCode)
      ?.label.toString();

    if (selectedLanguage) {
      this.bodyTag!.dir = localeCode === "ar" ? "rtl" : "ltr";
      this.siteLanguage = selectedLanguage;
      this.translate.use(localeCode);
    }
  }

....

//---------------------------------------
<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="languages">
      <mat-icon class="material-icons-outlined">languages</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <mat-menu #languages="matMenu" class="mymegamenu">
      <button
        (click)="changeSiteLanguage(language.code)"
        *ngFor="let language of languageList"
        mat-menu-item
      >
        {{ language.label }}
      </button>
    </mat-menu>
```

When the user change the language it applies only in the layout components, although in my JSON files I have translated everything

PS: I get no errors when using translate pipe in any components, so I think it is well imported
`<mat-label>{{ "Filter" | translate }} </mat-label>`

Thank you in advance

Comment: This might not be related but you probably don't need to import/export `TranslateModule` in your shared module, if you are already importing and configuring it in `NgxTranslateModule`. If you export your configured `TranslateModule` from within `NgxTranslateModule`, then other modules only need to import `NgxTranslateModule`

Comment: @nate-kumar Yes, you are right. I had the same outcome when I only imported NgxTranslateModule without TranslateModule